# vpc の lambda からインターネットにアクセスできないのはなぜ?

Tags: aws, network, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

AWS において、 デフォルトVPCの中のec2のインスタンスからは、普通にインターネットにアクセスできます。

一方、そのような ec2 インスタンスと同じサブネットに対して、 VPC 内 lambda を実行しても、インターネットにアクセスできない様子です。

どうして、同じサブネットなのに、ec2 ではインターネットにアクセスできるのに、 lambda ではアクセスできないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html

上記ドキュメントより:

1. 普通の ec2 インスタンスが、 InternetGateway で直にインターネットに接続できるのは、以下の条件を見たすとき。

   - EIP を持っている。
   - (Private IP <-> EIP の NAT 変換を行うのは Internet Gateway.)
2. VPC の Lambda は、対象のサブネットに ENI を作って、 Private IP アドレスのみを持つ。

   - なので、 EIP を持たず、 Internet Gateway を経由できない。

対応策は:

1. NAT gateway をパブリックサブネットに設置する。パブリックサブネットとは、 デフォルトの routing が InternetGateway につながっているサブネット。
2. ひとつサブネット(プライベートサブネットと呼ばれたりする)を作って、ルーティングのデフォルトを 1 の NAT gateway に設定する。
3. 2 のサブネットで lambda を動かす。